# SBOX_FATAL_MEMORY_EXCEEDED

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I wrote a code in javascript to export the report to excel using html. it works for 1 report but when I run multiple reports at the same place using for loop and try to export it to excel it gives me  an SBOX_FATAL_MEMORY_EXCEEDED error.

Please help me with it.

```js
function updateReportHidden(idCount) {
  if (idCount > 0) {
    var template = "";

    for (var a = 0; a <= idCount; a++) {
      template[a] = "<html><head><title>Document</title><script>window.chartAnimation = false;<\/script></head><body>" + $("#report" + a).html() + "</body></html>";
    }

    for (var b = 0; b <= idCount; b++) {
      var temp = $(".container div .hide");
      temp.remove();
      
      $("table").attr("border", "1");
      $(".container div").append(temp);
      $('#ReportHidden' + b).val("");
      $('#ReportHidden' + b).val(template[b]);
    }
  } else {
    $('#ReportHidden0').val("");
    var temp = $(".container div .hide");
    temp.remove();

    $("table").attr("border", "1");
    var template = "<html><head><title>Document</title><script>window.chartAnimation = false;<\/script></head><body>" + $("#report0").html() + "</body></html>";
    $('#ReportHidden0').val(template);
    $(".container div").append(temp);
  }
};
```

Comment: I searched for it a lot yesterday and this problem was connected with chrome everywhere regarding it's memory management, I tried it on Firefox too but it kept loading and it's loading never ends I tried waiting for half an hour on Firefox but it neither give any error nor completes the task.

Comment: It's not part of a chrome extension, it's from my own web application that I am developing.